# DataTemplate to Linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a ListBox of Dockpanels which display **"FieldName:, [*_*____]** *(user input textbox)*".   After the user populates the field, I'm looking for a LINQ way to take the  pairs and throw them into a KeyValuePair object.

```
     <DataTemplate x:Key="ExtraLoginInfoTemplate">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Name="CodeID" Text="{Binding Path=ID,Converter={BLL:CodeMarkupExtension}}" />
                        <TextBox Name="Input"/> 
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

    <ListBox Name="extraLoginInfoListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ExtraLoginInfoTemplate}"/>

    //codebehind

extraLoginInfoListBox.DataContext = cvList; //list of codevalue objects
```

---

```
private void submitButton_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  KeyValuePair<string,string> myInputs = /* ? some linq query to get the data from extraLoginInfoListBox */ 

}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have two way binding set up on your list box AND bindings set up on your template for the input. If you do that, then your data source will automatically update with values and then you can easily query via linq from your `cvList` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a property to be bound with your *Input* textbox to store whatever value was entered by user:

```
<TextBox Name="Input" Text="{Binding Path=IDValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And then, you can use following code:

```
var keyValuePairs = cvList.ToDictionary((obj) => obj.ID, (obj) => obj.IDValue);
```